# A word or phrase that can categorize students that are either currently attending or have had attended sometime in the past

Tags: terminology, tenses

We need to create a new category that represents that a person has actually attended the school, whether that is current or historical. I proposed 'Once Student', which seems tense neutral, but also a little confusing. For addtional context this will need to result in three categories:

- Student        (Is Attending)
- Former Student (Has Attended)
- Once Student   (Is Attending or Has Attended)

Can anyone give a better phrase for the third category?

Comment: To me the term _once student_ implies that they were once a student but aren't any longer.

Comment: .......Student.

Comment: This sounds like a form I recently had to fill out for SSA on behalf of my daughter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difficult. But someone who attends (or who has attended, and maybe even will attend in the future) is an ***attendee.*** While an attendee might usually attend an event, there's no reason it would not fit your context — especially if all you need is a column title `attendee` to hold Boolean values.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/attendee) uses the word for past, present and future attendances:

> The attendees did not realize that they were serving as guinea pigs to identify the operational problems.
>
> Many of those seminar attendees are taking an enormous gamble on apartment rents remaining high.
>
> There will be a panel discussion, followed by refreshments for all attendees.

Comment: I like it. "Student Attendee".  I think that it has enough inherent meaning, that anyone without institutional knowledge could make a reasonable guess as to what it means, but not confining, so that it allows us to attribute a technical business process meaning as well.
Thank you!